# Is there any software to solve game theoretical problems with manual/tutorial ?

Tags: game-theory

such as  solving 2x2/mxn game problem by using maximin minmax principle,mixed strategy,dominence property, modified dominance property,graphical method,matrix method, linear programming problem etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only software developed for finding equilibria in games is [Gambit](http://gambit.sourceforge.net/). I never worked with it so I do not know what it can do. At the same time finding equilibria in infinite games is a computational nightmare, so I would assume Gambit works only for finite games.

Maybe the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126744/is-a-simplex-method-appropriate-for-solving-nash-equilibria/2126757#2126757) will help as well?